# Get div content by id

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

I have a string that keeps entire html document. I would like to get all the content inside a div with specific id. For example:

```
<div id="myId" class = "myClass">
 <div class = "myClass">hello</div>
</div>
```

I need the content between the tag  with id="myId" and it's closing tag.
Any way to achieve this? The output should be the second line.

Comment: Are we talking about WebForms, MVC or WebApi? What have you tried and where is your code?

Comment: show us what you did so far please?

Comment: did you mean you need get HTML content if div with id myId in code behind??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The clean and correct way would be via an HTML parser, like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex):

```
string stringThatKeepsYourHtml = "<div id=....";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(stringThatKeepsYourHtml);
string whatUrLookingFor = doc.GetElementbyId("myId").InnerHtml;
```

Comment: What if adding a library to the solution is not an option? Should we go towards dirty text processing ways?

Comment: @AleX_ I doubt that would be a reasonable constraint in any real project and I'd recommend you challenge that first, but other than creating your own DOM parser, if you're dealing with small, predictable HTML, text processing can be a quick win.

Comment: In my case , how to find id by class name ?

 <div class = "myClass" id="1231">hello</div>

Comment: @saebAmini yes , select node did the trick

 ticketID = doc.DocumentNode
               .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='myClass']").Id;

Answer (score 4):

You want the `html` of inside the any `div` in `c#` code at the `server side` so you can do like this.

```
<div id="myId" class = "myClass" runat="server">
 <div class = "myClass">hello</div>
</div>
```

so you must be add the `runat="server"` attribute to that div to access that div on the `C#` code on the server.

and access like this:

```
Debug.WriteLine(myId.InnerHtml);
```

And check the `output` window you will get the `<div class = "myClass">hello</div>` this.

Happy Coding

Comment: While this is true if OP used ASP.NET it won't help if he just has to parse a HTML document. Then Saeb's answer would be more helpful.  OP: _"I have a string that keeps entire html document."_

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Make HTML element to runat = 'server' and give ID.

```
<div id="myId" class = "myClass" runat="server">
 <div class = "myClass">hello</div>
</div>
```

Step 2. Use below C# code to get Div HTML string.

```
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
       System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter h = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                myId.RenderControl(h);
                string str = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

- myId is your DIV Id.
- Or you can use HTML Agility Pack(HAP)