# How to get text from editable div content with c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, contenteditable

I have an editable div content which I keep some html texts. I added attribute `runat="server"` and wanna get the html text content with c#. Does anybody can help me with it? Here is my `div`

```
<div runat="server" id="Pcontent" contenteditable="true" class="allow">
     Some <em>rich</em> 
     <span style="font-size:2em">HTML</span> 
</div>
```

***PS: `InnerHtml` and `InnerText` does not working!!***

PS2: My purpose is generally like [here](https://jsbin.com/nozifexasu/edit?html,css,js,output). I want to get data from allowed div and use it as HTML string

> **SOLVED** : `var str = document.querySelector("[contenteditable]").textContent;`

Comment: This stackoverflow question may be helpfull for you [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689095/get-div-content-by-id)

Comment: First solution using the string version of content which I dont know. So its not useable for me. Second one is  using InnerHtml which that returned to me a blank. It did not worked for me :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
string stringThatKeepsYourHtml = "<div id=Pcontent....";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(stringThatKeepsYourHtml);
string whatUrLookingFor = doc.GetElementbyId("Pcontent").InnerHtml;
```

Comment: I dont know the content, end-user gives it.

Comment: well, there are few ways to access the content of div element! most common ones are InnerHtml or you have to build your own script. If the code above failed you, I would suggest you to try this: http://www.nullskull.com/q/10317531/to-get-divinnertextvalue-to-variable-string-from-code-behind.aspx